# Можно ли из md5(secret+"1") получить md5(sercret+"123")

Tags: криптография, хеширование

Если мы знаем хеш от пароля с солью и соль, можно ли теоретически не зная пароля вычислить на основе этих данных хеш от того-же пароля но с другой солью быстрее чем в случае подбора пароля? А хеш от пароля без соли?

Comment: если меня не подводит память - то да, сам пароль в этом случае вычислить на порядок легче, т.к. `digest(x) = carrier_digest.update(byte) for byte in x`

Comment: Вам сюда: [Атака удлинением сообщения](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Знание соли не делает алгоритм слабее, но без знания соли подобрать пароль не возможно. Алгоритм md5 имеет слишком короткую длину результирующего хеш-кода и уязвимости, что атакующему поможет уже само по себе. Существуют алгоритмы подбирающие md5 достаточно быстро.

Как верно замечено в комментариях, пароль который подойдет может оказаться не оригинальным паролем пользователя. Определить оригинальный пароль пользователя по хеш-коду не представляется возможным.

Comment: Точнее будет так, зная соль и md5-значение можно подобрать такой пароль, который возможно будет отличатся от исходного, но подойдёт поскольку даст такую-же md5  не смотря на отличие:)